# Visual StudioセットアッププロジェクトでマージモジュールのFolderが反映されない

Tags: visual-studio

[Visual Studio 2013のセットアッププロジェクト](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)でマージモジュールを使用したインストーラーを作成しています。

ソリューションエクスプローラーでセットアッププロジェクト内のマージモジュールを選択するとプロパティウィンドウで`Folder`を指定することが出来ますが、実際にインストールするとマージモジュールのファイルが`Application Folder`に出力されてしまいます。

マージモジュール側でフォルダを指定すれば出力フォルダを変更することは出来ますが、セットアッププロジェクト側で構成する手段は無いでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

マージモジュールのファイルがインストールされる先をセットアッププロジェクト側で指定したいということでしょうか？
もしそれならば「再ターゲット可能フォルダー」を使ってお望みのことができるかもしれません。
手順は次の通りです。

#### マージモジュールプロジェクト

1. 「ファイルシステム」を開く
2. 「モジュールの再ターゲット可能フォルダー」を追加する
3. 「モジュールの再ターゲット可能フォルダー」にインストールしたいファイルを追加する

#### セットアッププロジェクト

1. ソリューションエクスプローラーで（「モジュールの再ターゲット可能フォルダー」を追加した）マージモジュールを追加する
2. 「ファイルシステム」を開いてマージモジュールのインストール先フォルダーを作成する（「Application Folder\Foo」など）
3. マージモジュールのプロパティの「(MergeModuleProperties)」の中の「Module Retargetable Folder」で「(Browse)」を選択して2で作成したフォルダを指定する

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/777454/msm-merge-module-does-not-copy-to-correct-folder)によるとビルド後イベントで[SQLを実行してデータベースを更新する](http://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/deployment/editwidbprogrammatically.html)回避方法が推奨されているようです。